# NPOI HSSF vs SS namespace

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I'm trying to use the [NPOI library](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) in a winforms app. I have referenced the latest NPOI dll in my project and tried to reproduce the examples gave by NPOI and found on SO:

```
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
        HSSFRow headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);
```

But this won't compile on my machine because `HSSFWorkbook.CreateSheet()` returns a `NPOI.SS.UserModel.Sheet` instead of a `NPOI.SS.UserModel.HSSFSheet`.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Wild guess but have you tried casting the sheet into a HSSFSheet?

Comment: Have you clearly added in the references of your project the libraries NPOI.dll and NPOI.HSSF.dll ? With "using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;" in the usings, your code perfectly works for me. I'm using NPOI version 1.2.1.0

Comment: I had tried @Nathan but some weird behaviour further on in the code mad me think it wasn't the right solution. Anyway it seems it wasn't linked.

Comment: I personally would not trust a project when it uses names like that.  Just me though.

Comment: I downloaded the 1.2.3 version @PierrOz and there is no NPOI.HSSF.dll It is now all in the NPOI.dll Casting seems to be the way to go. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @Hans: it's a pity we can't down vote comments :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
Row headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);
```

And include the namespace `NPOI.SS.UserModel`

`Sheet` and `Row` are actually interfaces, but don't have the `I` prefix (I presume) because this library is a port from Java.

Comment: This also seems to work. I haven't checked the detailed history but I guess they added the interfaces in the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

The interface is prepared for NPOI 2.0 actually. In NPOI 2.0, there are two namespace: XSSF and HSSF. XSSF is for xlsx, HSSF is for xls. Both implements interfaces in NPOI.SS.

Answer (score 0):

using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
...
ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
IRow headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);